# How do I automatically delete my users firebase auth account when they cancel there stripe subscription?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am new to using Vue with Firebase for authentication and Cloud Firestore for the database. I have installed an extension that deletes all data in Firestore when an account is deleted. I am also using Stripe for subscription payments. Is there a way to automatically delete a user's authentication account when they cancel their subscription?

I noticed there is a `customer.subscription.deleted` event in Stripe when a customer cancels their subscription, but I am not sure how to use it. Is there any way to use this to either delete the Firebase auth or trigger something like this?

```js
const { deleteDoc } = useDocument('Premium', route.params.id )
const { deleteImage } = useStorage()
const handleDelete = async () => {
  alert("Warning once Subscription is cancelled all data including images, videos and all provided information will be deleted and this can not be undone or retrieved.")
      await deleteDoc()
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath2)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath3)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath4)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath5)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath6)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath7)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath8)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath9)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePath10)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePathv1)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePathv2)
      await deleteImage(Handler.value.filePathv3)
      router.push({ name: 'Home' })
      
}
```

This would delete the data in Firestore and in storage but not the Firebase auth. How would one use subscription being canceled with Stripe to trigger an event that would delete your Firebase auth? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't repost the same problem multiple times please. At best they will get closed, but it my get you banned from the site. Instead, address the feedback you got on your previous post there - by clicking the `edit` link under it. That'll also make that question eligible to be reopened.